# Training set and validation Set of different dimension

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, training-data

I am training a Super-Resolution Network in Keras. I have a **training set** with images of dimensions (64,64) and I have images of dimensions (128,128) that I want to use as a **validation set**. Does it make sense to have a validation set of different dimensions ? Or do both sets have to be the same dimensions ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a question.

> Do we require same sized image for CNN?

Until you are using a fully connected layer at the end of your network, you need not require same size images.

Comment: No, my network is fully Convolutional. Actually, if I use images of size 64x64 as a validation set, my network seems to overfit **but** if I use images of size 128x128 as validation set, there is no problem. But I don't know if this makes sense to 'compare' different sizes

Comment: No, there is no problem in having validation set image of different size. But what do you mean by "I use images of size 64x64 as a validation set, my network seems to overfit but if I use images of size 128x128 as validation set, there is no problem" ?

Comment: When my validation set is images of 64x64, the validation loss is always above the training loss. When I use images of 128x128 as validation my validation loss is below my training loss during the training